# Inverse Affine Transform - Rasterio

Tags: python, gis, rasterio

Is there a build in way in rasterio to compute the inverse affine transform of an `rasterio.transform.Affine` object?

I'm currently doing the following:

```py
from rasterio.transform import Affine
import numpy as np

transform = Affine(29.976, 0, 5.12e5, 0, -29.976, 6.94e6)

matrix_form_transform = np.vstack(
    [
        np.array(transform.column_vectors).T,
        np.array([0,0,1])
    ]
)

matrix_form_inverse_transform = np.linalg.inv(matrix_form_transform)

inverse_transform = Affine(*matrix_form_inverse_transform[:2, :].ravel())

print(inverse_transform * transform)
# Affine(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
#        -0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

This is quite clunky and I feel like there should be a builtin way to get to this but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Affine` class is defined in the `affine` package which is also managed by the rasterio organization. The `Affine` class implements the `__invert__` dunder method. This means that it implements the ability to use the `~` operator. As it happens the implementation for `__invert__` finds the inverse `Affine` object.

You can do one of the following:

```py
from rasterio.transform import Affine

transform = Affine(29.976, 0, 5.12e5, 0, -29.976, 6.94e6)
print(~transform * transform)
# | 1.00, 0.00, 0.00|
# | 0.00, 1.00, 0.00|
# | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
```

or if you want to be more explicit

```py
from rasterio.transform import Affine

transform = Affine(29.976, 0, 5.12e5, 0, -29.976, 6.94e6)
print(transform.__invert__() * transform)
# | 1.00, 0.00, 0.00|
# | 0.00, 1.00, 0.00|
# | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
```